# Django request with user criteria

Tags: django

I would like to get some help about my future process. I would like that users could create his own django request and then get the result.

Up to now, I created django requests in my script but there are static requests :

`request1 = Test.objects.all()`

or

```
    query_lastname_ID = request.GET.get('q1ID')
    query_firstname_ID = request.GET.get('q1bisID')
    query_naissance_ID = request.GET.get('q1terID')

    if query_firstname_ID and query_lastname_ID and query_naissance_ID :

        query_ID_list = Individu.objects.filter(
                                                Nom__icontains=query_lastname_ID, 
                                                Prenom__icontains=query_firstname_ID,
                                                VilleNaissance__icontains=query_naissance_ID)
        if len(query_ID_list) != 0 :
            messages.success(request, 'Miracle .. Vous avez un résultat !')
        else :
            messages.error(request, "Oh non .. Vous n'avez aucun résultat !")
```

All of these requests are static.

Now I would like to let the choice to the user between criteria or mathematic operator.

I won't write table fields in my request but the user could have the choice to get what he wants :

- one field
- two fields
- x fields
- the mathematic operator (=, >, <, not egal, ...)
- comparison between fields
- ...

User could get a result thanks to a dynamic request. He could create himself Django request.

Is it possible ? I don't find example or documentations about this kind of process :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try create filter as dict, for example:

```
map_fields_get = {
    'Nom': 'q1ID', 'Prenom': 'q1bisID', 'VilleNaissance': 'q1terID'
}
condition_param = 'YOUR_GET_NAME_FOR_CONDITION'
condition_list = ['icontains', 'iexact', 'gt', 'lt']
condition = request.GET.get('condition_param', 'icontains')
if condition not in condition_list:
    # add your logic set default or raise
    condition = condition_list[0]
qs_f = {}
for get_f, f in map_fields_get.items():
    get_val = request.GET.get(get_f, None)
    if get_val:
        qs_f_key = '%s__%s' % (f, condition)
        qs_f[qs_f_key] = get_val

if qs_f:
    query_ID_list = Individu.objects.filter(**qs_f)
```

Comment: Wouaw I have to read with attention your script. First time I'm trying to make this kind of things !